# is this a correct recursive function

Tags: python-3.x

can some one please explain why this give me error:unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

```
def func(a, b):

  if a >= 0 and b > 0 and isinstance(b,int) :

   if b == 1 :
    return a
   elif b > 1 and b%2 == 1 :
    return  a * func(a,(b-1)/2)*func(a,(b-1)/2)

   else :
    return func(a,b/2) * func(a, b/2)
```

Comment: how do you call your function? and why not `func(a,(b-1)/2)**2` instead of `func(a,(b-1)/2)*func(a,(b-1)/2)`?

Comment: I am pretty new to coding so I thought the mistake was type of operation or how its written.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Python 3x, in which the result of the operator `/` is always a `float` value, not an `int`.

Supposed you call `func(5, 4)`, the program then calls `func(5, 2.0) * func(5, 2.0)`. It doesn't satisfy the condition `isinstance(b, int)` and you don't provide a `return` statement for this case, thus, `func(5, 2.0) * func(5, 2.0)` equals `None * None`.

If you want an `int` from the division operator, use `//` instead of `/`

Comment: I think this is not the only problem I adjusted it and still having issues with assert test ,I think am doing recursive functions in a totally wrong way , I can't get the idea of recursive functions at all.

Comment: What exactly are your "issues with assert test"? I guess `func(a,b)` means `a` to the power `b`. If you change every `/` into `//`, your function is correct but not very good in terms of performance. You should change as @hiro protagonist suggested: `func(a,b/2) * func(a, b/2)` into `func(a,b/2) ** 2`. Also, you should handle the case `a >= 0 and b > 0 and isinstance(b,int)` not true, probably raise a `TypeError`

Comment: Yeah I got the problem fixed it was a data type issue as the function was returning a float ,it was just a little bit of a hassle with syntax errors ,@hiro was right I just didn't understand that fast.